# Netlogo foreach with if statements

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of lists(with a coords list inside) and wish to filter through contents of the inner lists and if it matches a result I would like to delete it. I am having trouble iterating through the list and then the list second list.

DATA:

```
[[14.142135623730951 [-2 -16] "15"] [13.601470508735444 [-4 -17] "15"] [21.93171219946131 [-4 -17] "16"] [27.294688127912362 [-4 -17] "14"] [15.524174696260024 [-4 -17] "13"]]
```

My Attempt:

```
set coords [-4 -17]
    foreach[distanceQueue]
    [
    if(item ? item 1 distanceQueue = coords)[set distanceQueue remove-item ? distanceQueue]

    ]
```

Where `item ?` should be the current iteration of the foreach loop and item 1 should be the second element of that array.

Can anyone assist me in making this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking for `filter`. E.g.,

```
to-report test
  let lst [
    [14.142135623730951 [-2 -16] "15"] 
    [13.601470508735444 [-4 -17] "15"] 
    [21.93171219946131 [-4 -17] "16"] 
    [27.294688127912362 [-4 -17] "14"] 
    [15.524174696260024 [-4 -17] "13"]
  ]
  let coords [-4 -17]
  report filter [[?] -> coords != item 1 ?] lst
end
```